# Can using try as a condition cause problems?

Tags: python, try-catch

I've done this in one of my programs, it works as intended but I would like to know if using try as a condition in this way this way could cause problems (the exception is raised around a third of the time)

```
try:
    # This line create a condition by raising or not the error
    next(external_data.cursor.execute(statement))
    return 'C'
except StopIteration:
    return 'F'
```

Comment: Avoid creating SQL statements by concatenating strings and variables. That's how SQL injection happens. Use prepared statements, pretty please.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. AFAIK Python even uses exceptions internally to break loops. The only thing that could happen is, that you catch exceptions, that actually should have been raised.